# after generating eclipse configuration for play framework, play repository library show me so ugly

Tags: java, eclipse, frameworks, playframework

Hello I'm a newbie for play framework.

I just started to learn play.

Anyway I try to make new project

"play new test1"

and generate eclipse configuration

"play"

"eclipse"

after opening the project on eclipse, all kind of jar files, play repository, are the same line.

like this.

```
test1
+app
+test
+classes_managed
+play-java-jdbc_2.10.jar
+play-jdbc_2.10.jar
.
.
(so many jar files)
.
.
+JRE System Library
+scala-library.jar
+conf
+project
+public
+target
+build.sbt
+README
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse, you need to use "show view" then find "package view"... instead of "project view"... hope this help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but just now i found that my perspective is for java EE not Java. After Changing Perpective, I could get the environment which I want.